# How to check if dates within intervals in R with Loop function?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to check that how many location points of predator are in those pastures with cattle during grazing period.

Here is my data format of cattle information, from `DateIntoPasture` to `DateoutofPasture` that is the time that cattle are in that pasture.
For example, from `2015/5/1` to `2015/5/10`, there are cattle in pasture `"a"`

```
 Pasture DateIntoPasture DateoutofPasture
  a        2015/5/1        2015/5/10
  b        2015/5/5        2015/10/1
```

Here is data format of predators:

```
  PointID PASNAME      Date
    1       a      2015/5/5
    2       a      2015/5/5
    3       b      2015/5/1
    4       b      2015/5/6
```

I think I need to use Loop function to check every location point of predator, if they meet the requirements that `predatordata$PASNAME` has same name found in `cattledata$Pasture`, then go to next step to check if `predatordata$Date` is within interval that created by `cattledata$DateIntoPasture` and `cattledata$DateoutofPasture` of that same pasture. If a point meets two `requirments(name,date)`, then print a `"Yes"`, if not, print `NA`.

I think I may need to use `for` Loop in R, but just could not figure out how to check pasture name and how to check if date is within that period. Should I use `%in%` to check name? How could I put this two Loops together?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will find below a somewhat long solution, that will get you the count of predators for each pasture. It uses the "dplyr" package to transform dates in the right format and then iterates through the pasture data to find how many predators satisfy the conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

# Set up dataset for pasture
pasture <- c("a", "b", "c")
date.into.pasture <- c("2015/05/01", "2015/05/05", "2015/05/10")
date.out.of.pasture <- c("2015/06/01", "2015/06/05", "2015/06/10")
pasture.data.tmp <- data.frame(pasture = pasture, date.into = date.into.pasture, date.out.of = date.out.of.pasture)

# Set up dataset for predators
predator.pasture <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
predator.dates <- c("2015/04/01", "2015/05/05", "2015/05/10", "2015/05/20", "2015/06/20", "2015/07/10")
predator.data.tmp <- data.frame(pasture = predator.pasture, dates = predator.dates)

# Transform the dates into Date format
pasture.data <- pasture.data.tmp %>% mutate(date.into = as.Date(date.into), date.out.of = as.Date(date.out.of))
predator.data <- predator.data.tmp %>% mutate(dates = as.Date(dates))

# Count predators for each pasture
predator.counts = c()
for (pa in pasture.data$pasture) {
  date.into = pasture.data$date.into[pasture == pa]
  date.out.of = pasture.data$date.out.of[pasture == pa]
  predator <- predator.data[predator.data$pasture == pa & predator.data$dates >= pasture.data$date.into & predator.data$dates < pasture.data$date.out.of,]
  predator.counts <- c(predator.counts, nrow(predator))
}

# Get the predator counts in the pasture data
pasture.data$predator.counts <- predator.counts
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, let me try your way after I check the format of my dates, they are in chaos now. Sometimes after I convert date data in Excel to CSV, they become in chaos. I think it has something to do with date format by setting, but it always happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

```
df <- merge(cattleData, predatorData, by.x = "Pasture", by.y = "PASNAME")
li <- lapply(df[, c(2,3,5)], as.POSIXct, "%Y/%m/%d")
ifelse(li$Date > li$DateIntoPasture & li$Date < li$DateoutofPasture, "yes", "NA")
[1] "yes" "yes" "NA"  "yes"
```

Comment: Thank you Psidom, you answered this question so fast!

Comment: I think it works on my data, I just need to figure out how to calculate number of the true value now. like how many yes showed up in result. Really appreciate it my friend

Comment: `sum(li$Date > li$DateIntoPasture & li$Date < li$DateoutofPasture)` will give the number of true values.